# Forming Bigrams of words in list of sentences with Python

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, nltk, collocation

I have a list of sentences:

```
text = ['cant railway station','citadel hotel',' police stn'].
```

I need to form bigram pairs and store them in a variable. The problem is that when I do that, I get a pair of sentences instead of words. Here is what I did:

```
text2 = [[word for word in line.split()] for line in text]
bigrams = nltk.bigrams(text2)
print(bigrams)
```

which yields

```
[(['cant', 'railway', 'station'], ['citadel', 'hotel']), (['citadel', 'hotel'], ['police', 'stn'])
```

Can't railway station and citadel hotel form one bigram. What I want is

```
[([cant],[railway]),([railway],[station]),([citadel,hotel]), and so on...
```

The last word of the first sentence should not merge with the first word of second sentence.
What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Using [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [zip](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> text = ["this is a sentence", "so is this one"]
>>> bigrams = [b for l in text for b in zip(l.split(" ")[:-1], l.split(" ")[1:])]
>>> print(bigrams)
[('this', 'is'), ('is', 'a'), ('a', 'sentence'), ('so', 'is'), ('is', 'this'), ('this',     
'one')]
```

Comment: and if you want to keep each sentence's bigrams in its own list: `[[b for b in zip(l.split(" ")[:-(n-1)], l.split(" ")[(n-1):])] for l in x]`

Comment: This is a wonderful approach for the general case and solves the OP's question straightforwardly but it is also worth mentioning that it is sometimes useful to treat punctuation marks as separate words e.g. if the intent is to train an n-gram language model, in order to calculate the grammaticality of a sentence so .split(" ") may not be the ideal here. It may be best to use nltk.word_tokenize along with nltk.sent_tokenize instead

Answer (score 18):

```
from nltk import word_tokenize 
from nltk.util import ngrams


text = ['cant railway station', 'citadel hotel', 'police stn']
for line in text:
    token = word_tokenize(line)
    bigram = list(ngrams(token, 2)) 

    # the '2' represents bigram; you can change it to get ngrams with different size
```

Answer (score 9):

Rather than turning your text into lists of strings, start with each sentence separately as a string. I've also removed punctuation and stopwords, just remove these portions if irrelevant to you:

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
from nltk.tokenize import WordPunctTokenizer
from nltk.collocations import BigramCollocationFinder
from nltk.metrics import BigramAssocMeasures

def get_bigrams(myString):
    tokenizer = WordPunctTokenizer()
    tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(myString)
    stemmer = PorterStemmer()
    bigram_finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(tokens)
    bigrams = bigram_finder.nbest(BigramAssocMeasures.chi_sq, 500)

    for bigram_tuple in bigrams:
        x = "%s %s" % bigram_tuple
        tokens.append(x)

    result = [' '.join([stemmer.stem(w).lower() for w in x.split()]) for x in tokens if x.lower() not in stopwords.words('english') and len(x) > 8]
    return result
```

To use it, do like so:

```
for line in sentence:
    features = get_bigrams(line)
    # train set here
```

Note that this goes a little further and actually statistically scores the bigrams (which will come in handy in training the model).

Comment: `stemmer` changes `apple` to `appl` so I get `['appl basket']`.

Comment: Yeah there are some limitations with Porter stemmer.

Comment: but this is not by sentences, you should use ``from_documents``.

Answer (score 5):

Without nltk:

```
ans = []
text = ['cant railway station','citadel hotel',' police stn']
for line in text:
    arr = line.split()
    for i in range(len(arr)-1):
        ans.append([[arr[i]], [arr[i+1]]])


print(ans) #prints: [[['cant'], ['railway']], [['railway'], ['station']], [['citadel'], ['hotel']], [['police'], ['stn']]]
```

Comment: are they bigrams by default? because i'll be needing them for spell correct.

Comment: @Sword you can see that it generates only bigrams from the last line (before the print). Play with it, try different sentences and see for yourself ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> text = ['cant railway station','citadel hotel',' police stn']
>>> bigrams = [(ele, tex.split()[i+1]) for tex in text  for i,ele in enumerate(tex.split()) if i < len(tex.split())-1]
>>> bigrams
[('cant', 'railway'), ('railway', 'station'), ('citadel', 'hotel'), ('police', 'stn')]
```

Using enumerate and split function.

Answer (score 2):

## Read the dataset

```
df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', skiprows = 6, index_col = "No")
```

## Collect all available months

```
df["Month"] = df["Date(ET)"].apply(lambda x : x.split('/')[0])
```

## Create tokens of all tweets per month

```
tokens = df.groupby("Month")["Contents"].sum().apply(lambda x : x.split(' '))
```

## Create bigrams per month

```
bigrams = tokens.apply(lambda x : list(nk.ngrams(x, 2)))
```

## Count bigrams per month

```
count_bigrams = bigrams.apply(lambda x : list(x.count(item) for item in x))
```

## Wrap up the result in neat dataframes

```
month1 = pd.DataFrame(data = count_bigrams[0], index= bigrams[0], columns= ["Count"])
month2 = pd.DataFrame(data = count_bigrams[1], index= bigrams[1], columns= ["Count"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Just fixing Dan's code:

```
def get_bigrams(myString):
    tokenizer = WordPunctTokenizer()
    tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(myString)
    stemmer = PorterStemmer()
    bigram_finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(tokens)
    bigrams = bigram_finder.nbest(BigramAssocMeasures.chi_sq, 500)

    for bigram_tuple in bigrams:
        x = "%s %s" % bigram_tuple
        tokens.append(x)

    result = [' '.join([stemmer.stem(w).lower() for w in x.split()]) for x in tokens if x.lower() not in stopwords.words('english') and len(x) > 8]
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to use **"zip" function** to generate the n-gram.
Where **2 in range** function is number of grams

```
test = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print(test[0:])
print(test[1:])
print(list(zip(test[0:],test[1:])))
%timeit list(zip(*[test[i:] for i in range(2)]))
```

**o/p:**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]  
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]  
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8), (8, 9)]  
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.34 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a **number of ways** to solve it but I solved in this way:

```
>>text = ['cant railway station','citadel hotel',' police stn']
>>text2 = [[word for word in line.split()] for line in text]
>>text2
[['cant', 'railway', 'station'], ['citadel', 'hotel'], ['police', 'stn']]
>>output = []
>>for i in range(len(text2)):
    output = output+list(bigrams(text2[i]))
>>#Here you can use list comphrension also
>>output
[('cant', 'railway'), ('railway', 'station'), ('citadel', 'hotel'), ('police', 'stn')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best and most general way to do it is the following:

```
n      = 2
ngrams = []

for l in L:
    for i in range(n,len(l)+1):
        ngrams.append(l[i-n:i])
```

or in other words:

```
ngrams = [ l[i-n:i] for l in L for i in range(n,len(l)+1) ]
```

This should work for any `n` and any sequence `l`. If there are no ngrams of length `n` it returns the empty list.